# Trying to access all calendars of type local or CalDAV type

Tags: swift

I am trying to make an array of only calendars of type = CalDAV.

EKCalendar <0x137ec1800> {title = Work; type = CalDAV; allowsModify = YES; color = #63DA38;}]

```
print("p477 calendar.type: \(calendar.type)")
```

"p477 calendar.type: EKCalendarType"

so not sure how to extract local calendars only. Trying to match all calendars that have type = CalDAV This gives error: "Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'EKCalendarType' and 'String'

```
  if calendar.type == "CalDAV" {
                        print("p472 we here in match?")
                        calendarArray.append(calendarTitle)
                    }
```

thanks for help. I have tried and tried for hours and hours, tried several different things.  tried:   if calendar.source.sourceType == EKSourceType.Local {